# Is using HTML controls in asp.net effective than using asp.net control.?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have been working and developing website in asp.net. Now, I want to try HTML5 and html controls in my asp.net website. It came to when I was reading that using HTML(5) controls and flex make the website lighter. I am following W3 schools. Can I get some more knowledge on using the html controls in asp.net websites.? Can I get some useful links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely do not want to add `ViewState` overhead, then use HTML controls rather than ASP.NET server controls. But beware, `ViewState` is the glue for a lot of ASP.NET server controls being able to "remember" their values between post backs to the server.

If you want more control over the output HTML, then use HTML controls, because the HTML control will map directly to the corresponding HTML element, rather than be rendered as potentially another HTML element or group of HTML elements, for example:

- ASP.NET `Literal` server control will not render as an element, but rather just text.
- ASP.NET `GridView` server control will render as an HTML `table` container, by default, and then literal text for `BoundField`s and various other elements for `TemplateField`s.
- ASP.NET `CheckBoxList` server control will render as an HTML `table` container and then an `input` element for each individual check box.
- ASP.NET `TextBox` will render as an HTML `input` element if it is single line of text or as an HTML `textarea` if it is multiple lines of text.

Finally, in some ASP.NET Frameworks, like SharePoint, certain server controls get rendered differently depending upon how many items are in the result. For example if you have a lookup list with 19 or fewer items, then SharePoint will render the items as simple drop list (HTML element `option` with a `select` element for each value), but if the amount of items is 20 or more, then SharePoint decides to render a more complex combo box with jQuery support for auto-suggest. This is a case where you are at the mercy of the ASP.NET rendering engine for what ultimate HTML is produced.

Answer (score 0):

check out the link 

[Difference Between ASP.NET Server Controls,HTML Server Controls and HTML Intrinsic Controls](http://www.extremeexperts.com/Net/FAQ/DiffBetweenServerandHTMLControls.aspx)    I think this will help you to understand the difference between asp.net controls and html controls